# Twisted (Python) - what is the difference between cooperate and coiterate?

Tags: python, twisted

The docs here 
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.html#cooperate
 suggest that the difference is that cooperate returns a CooperativeTask whereas coiterate returns a Deferred (evidenced by my own tests, not specified in docs). I've invested the weekend learning the basics of Twisted, so I understand what a Deferred is and I've been a good boy sending my blocking code off to threads/processes. I understand coiterate goes as fast as Twisted allows it, whereas LoopingCall tries to fire at the selected interval.

My hunch is that cooperate() tasks are done inside CooperativeTask objects and coiterate() within Deferred objects. If someone can summarize the differences in behavior between cooperate and coiterate I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost, but not exactly.  `cooperate` is a slightly newer API than `coiterate`.  `cooperate` is generally just a slightly better version of `coiterate` and you pretty much always want to use it.  Returning a `CooperativeTask` confers two benefits.  First, you can [pause](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.CooperativeTask.html#pause) and [resume](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.CooperativeTask.html#resume) the task without [stopping](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.CooperativeTask.html#stop) it, and second, you can generate [multiple Deferreds](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.CooperativeTask.html#whenDone) that notify you of when the task is done without interfering with each other, rather than just the one.

Both `coiterate` and `cooperate` produce a `CooperativeTask` under the hood, and both use a very short interval `LoopingCall` as their default scheduler.  If you want to use a different task scheduler you can always instantiate your own [`Cooperator`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.Cooperator.html).

(By the way, if there's no doc bug yet for the fact that `coiterate` returns a `Deferred`, please file one.)

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for and then some. Thanks!